# How do I use the toast feature?

Tags: android, syntax-error

I just started learning Android Studio. I want to display a toast notification by pressing a button on the widget. However, there is an error when using the getApplicationContext() function. Can you tell me how to fix it? Other things, including getBaseContext(), were the same..... The error message was "Cannot resolve method" getApplicationContext () ""  I didn't speak English, so I used Google Translator.... I'm so sorry if you can't understand...

```
package com.jhjsapp.widget;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    public void butcli(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"버튼 눌림", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is JAVA code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLjBc.png)

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to build an `AppWidget`? Why not start with something more basic?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show `Toast` message using `getApplicationContext()` because the Widget extends **AppWidgetProvider**. So you cannot get the current context.

You can try something like this :

```
public class testWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainPage.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
   }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    super.onReceive(context, intent);   
    Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help.Thanks to you guys, I've been able to fix it!!

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable first

```
private Context context;
```

then initialize context by adding this line to updateAppWidget() and onUpdate() and onEnabled() and onDisabled();

```
this.context=context;
```

then use toast like :

```
Toast.makeText(context,"버튼 눌림", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```